# How to create a fast autocomplete feature on the back-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, data-structures

I'm quite new to data structures but I was trying to implement an efficient city lookup / city autocomplete feature on the back-end of my application (A nodeJS express server).

Originally I was only loading in memory an array of cities (which was around 20.000 cities); I'd let my client app search a city through the endpoint `/search` and return them a list of cities that matched what the user was searching:

```
import cities from './cities.json';

// Search endpoint
app.get('/search', (req, res) => {
  const results = [];
  const searchKey = req.body.key.toLowerCase();

  for (let city of cities) {
    if (city.toLowerCase().contains(searchKey)) {
      results.push(city);

      // Max 10 cities
      if (results.length > 10) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  res.json(cities);
});
```

Although this works fast because I only have 20.000 cities, I assume it's pretty bad in term of time complexity as the worst case complexity is `O(n)`.

So I was thinking of implementing a suffix-tree based dictionary so the lookup for a key would have a complexity of `O(m)`, `m` being the length of the key (correct me if I'm wrong) at the cost of a higher space complexity.

But as I say I'm a bit new to all of this so my questions are:

**1)** What is usually done to implement a fast autocomplete feature ?

**2)** Would it be better if I store my cities in a SQL database ? Is there a way to efficiently configure a database table to allow a fast suffix-based lookup ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my experience, ElasticSearch can be a solution for autocomplete. It is scalable and powerful. Some recommended tutorials to read:

- https://hackernoon.com/elasticsearch-building-autocomplete-functionality-494fcf81a7cf
- https://qbox.io/blog/build-autocomplete-feature-using-elasticsearch-suggest
  => this one using cities data as example, might fit your case.

You can also find some autocomplete documentation in their official docs:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/search-suggesters-completion.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links !

Answer (score -4):

Consider use Autocomplete (jquery UI)
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: jQuery's autocomplete is a front-end solution, but the question is related to the back-end.